# Services configuration description

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have several Spring applications. Specially, we are moving to SpringBoot. For example, let's say we have application A and application B. A and B, can be deployed with different spring.profiles.active, like local, dev, qa, uat and prod. And for each profile, there are several configurations, like data base URL, 3rd parties URL, cron expressions, and a lot more.

Let's say I deploy application A somewhere. Is there an automatized way to get a report with all the environment variable configuration? Like http://localhost:8080/applicationA/configurationReport? Like a JSP page or json or whatever.

Maybe something which Spring ships with?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will resolve your properties via the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

This runs during bean creation and resolves all your placeholders to what it's found in your configuration files for runtime.

You won't just be able to see the mappings once the app is running like you would JVM arguments.

As a poor crux you could log non sensitive property values to the logs by a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` which will run after the properties have been set. Or create a service to load the .properties files during runtime and return the read values via an exposed url.